# India TCS tax on foreign remittence

Tags: india, tax-deduction, international-transfer

I am an NRI with some NRO and NRE accounts held in an Indian Bank.

I am trying to remit an amount from sale of a property for which TDS has already been paid. The amount was deposited to an account that has been held in my name. [Will I be subject to this TCS Tax which seems to have been raised from 5% to 20% since July 2023](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/tax/new-tcs-rule-to-come-into-effect-from-october-1-2023-finance-ministry/articleshow/101345956.cms) ?

Answer (score 0):

No. NRIs and OCIs can repatriate upto USD 1 million without being subject to TCS. However, if a resident Indian is remitting money abroad, then they are subject to TCS.

Source: Multiple websites.